# TCL\TK Resize window : bind

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have problem when I resize my window ,I don't understand why, when I move my window `.` my another window created with `.c bind cir <1> [list window %x %y]` do not follow my window `.`
I believe that I've to use `<Configure>` as option, but I don't know how to do

Thanks for your help

My code below :

```
proc window {crx cry} {

set w1 .win
catch {destroy $w1}
toplevel $w1

wm minsize $w1 300 100
wm maxsize $w1 300 100

label $w1.l -text "$crx $cry"

pack $w1.l

}

wm state . zoomed

canvas .c -bg ivory

.c create oval 2 1.5 25 25 -fill #33FF00 -tag cir
.c create oval 30 30 50 50 -fill #33FF00 -tag cir1
.c create oval 60 60 90 90 -fill #33FF00 -tag cir2
.c create oval 90 90 130 130 -fill #33FF00 -tag cir3

pack .c -fill both -expand 1

.c bind cir <1> [list window %x %y]
.c bind cir1 <1> [list window %x %y]
.c bind cir2 <1> [list window %x %y]
.c bind cir3 <1> [list window %x %y]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's bad GUI design to make a whole group of windows move as one; it confuses users. That said…

The `<Configure>` event is sent to a widget whenever it is “reconfigured”, which mostly these days means that its location *relative to its parent* and size are altered. You have to use the main `bind` command, and if you `bind` to a toplevel you need to remember that toplevels also listen to the events generated by their non-toplevel children by default; you usually need some filtering.

```
bind . <Configure> {
    if {"%W" eq [winfo toplevel %W]} {
        puts "reconfigured %W: (%x,%y) %wx%h"
    }
}
```

Once you have the filtered events you want, compute the updated geometries and apply them with `wm geometry`.