# tcl/tk panedwindows, how to define a percentage size for child windows so that manual resizing keeps the display ratio?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, percentage

i'm relatively new to tk interface building and trying to figure out a few stuff before starting to write what i need

find below a stupid layout to use as an example

what i'd like to achieve is that when resizing the root window or (any sub panedwindows), all child windows inside get resized while keeping a say 50% space ratio

while atm, when for example i resize the root window to the left, the yellow textbox gets shrinked until it disappears completely (and so on for the blue one)

what i'd like is that my two half panes (the yellow one and the one containing the black,blue and green ones) keeps displaying evenly on each halves

same for the other 2 nested panedwindows obviously

it seems like that at some point in time panedwindows used to accept a "fraction" argument that would have allowed that but it doesn't seem to anymore

thanks in advance for your help, and if my code is too clumsy and you feel like providing an improved one along with the answer to my question, much obliged

```
#!/bin/sh
#The next line executes wish - wherever it is \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

proc bindings {} {
    bind . <Alt-Key-x> exit
    bind . <Alt-Key-k> redraw
    bind . <Key-Escape> exit

    bind . <Key> { puts [focus] }
}       

proc redraw {} {
    # which window has focus
    set foc [focus]

    puts "kill and redraw focused windows $foc"

    destroy $foc

    if { [string equal $foc ".t1"] } {
        upleftbox
        .sp3 paneconfigure .t1 -before .t2
    } elseif { [string equal $foc ".t2"] } {
        uprightbox
        .sp3 paneconfigure .t2 -after .t1
    } elseif { [string equal $foc ".t3"] } {
        bottombox
        .sp2 paneconfigure .t3 -after .sp3
    } elseif { [string equal $foc ".t4"] } {
        sidebox
       .sp1 paneconfigure .t4 -after .sp2
    }       
}

proc scrolled_text { f args } {
    #----------------------------------------------
    # scrolled_text from Brent Welch's book
    #----------------------------------------------

    frame $f
    eval {text $f.text -wrap none \
        -xscrollcommand [list $f.xscroll set] \
        -yscrollcommand [list $f.yscroll set]} $args
    scrollbar $f.xscroll -orient horizontal \
        -command [list $f.text xview]
    scrollbar $f.yscroll -orient vertical \
        -command [list $f.text yview]
    grid $f.text $f.yscroll -sticky nsew
    grid $f.xscroll -sticky nsew
    grid rowconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
    grid columnconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
    return $f.text
}

# structure is .sp1.sp2.sp3 
# defining the layout
proc sp1 {} {
    panedwindow .sp1 -orient h -opaqueresize 0 -sashwidth 10
}

proc sp2 {} {
    panedwindow .sp2 -orient v -opaqueresize 0 -sashwidth 10
}

proc sp3 {} {
    panedwindow .sp3 -orient h -opaqueresize 0 -sashwidth 10
}

# demo textboxes to populate the 4 windows GUI
proc upleftbox {} {
    text .t1 -background black -foreground lightgreen -width 18 -height 8
}

proc uprightbox {} {
    text .t2 -background blue -foreground lightgreen -width 18 -height 8
}

proc bottombox {} {
    text .t3 -background green -foreground lightgreen -width 18 -height 8
}

proc sidebox {} {
    text .t4 -background yellow -foreground lightgreen -width 18 -height 8
}

# Main

# define basics stuff
tk_setPalette background black foreground lightgreen
wm title . paf.tk
wm minsize . 50 60

bindings

# building basic layout

# call the windows proc
sp1
sp2
sp3
sidebox
bottombox
uprightbox
upleftbox

# build the windows like russian dolls

grid .sp1 -in . -sticky nsew 

.sp1 add .sp2 .t4
.sp2 add .sp3 .t3
.sp3 add .t1 .t2

# set the weight for expanding when resizing on the fly
grid columnconfigure . .sp1     -weight 1
grid rowconfigure    . .sp1     -weight 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCL\TK Resize window : bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702695/tcl-tk-resize-window-bind). You can use the same principle here. You can add the new binding to your `bindings` proc and resize the panels you need to resize.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) i'm reviewing both atm, see which one is the most suitable before i accept one. 

i get the idea, however what i wonder with yours is how handy it would it be if the differents text boxes were resized arbitrarily by a user instead of being fixed and definitive from the start and then root gets resized, having to keep these ratios.

in that case i'd need to get the ratio of each sub-windows at any point in time so that i can keep any arbitrarily set ratios (? if so, doable) unless i missed something

Comment: i think it could be done as you suggest, but unless i looked for something too complicated to do it or i'm just not good enough at coding, it might prove difficult to deal with a complex layout, so i'll keep it simple and use ttk:panedwindows instead. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ttk::panedwindow` instead of `panedwindow`. Its `add` subcommand has the `-weight` option, wich automatically resize child windows according to their weight.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) i'm reviewing both atm, see which one is the most suitable before i accept one

Comment: ttk::panedwindow is the easiest way to achieve what i want, thanks mate :)